# SVG element is not visible when I wrap them in group tag

Tags: html, svg

I need to draw an octagon with a STOP text in it. So basically it is a stop sign. Then, next to it, I need to draw the same thing, but rotated 90 degrees. Then next to it, same thing rotated 180 degrees. Then, below those three, draw another stop sign that rotates. When I draw the first shape, no problem I can see it. But when when I wrap it in  tags in order to draw the rest of the shapes, the first shape disappears as in not getting rendered. What am I doing wrong here? I am new to HTML5...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
        <head>
        <title>SVG Sample</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="html5_1.css">
    </head>
    <body>

         <svg width="500" height="300"> 

            <defs>
                <g id="myGroup">

                    <polygon points="50,5   100,5  125,30  125,80 100,105 
50,105  25,80  25, 30" 
                    style="stroke:#660000; fill:#cc3333; stroke-width:3;"> 
   </polygon>
                    <text x=38 y=65 font-family="san-serif" font- 
   size="32px" fill="white">STOP</text>
                </g>

            </defs>
        <use x="5" y="5" xlink:href="#myGroup" />
        <use x="5" y="5" xlink:href="#myGroup" transform="translate(110,0)"/>
        <use x="5" y="5" xlink:href="#myGroup" transform="translate(220,0)"/>

        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have not yet created other shapes. I think I know how to do that. My concern is why the shape I created disappears when I wrap it in defs and g tags.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/defs) : "The <defs> element is used to store graphical objects that will be used **at a later time**. Objects created inside a <defs> element are not rendered directly."

Comment: Oh, so I sort of define it (shape, color, etc) and then render it using <use> tag?

Comment: Try `<use xlink:href="#myGroup" />`

Comment: I added three lines to render the graphics and it comes out fine, thanks! Now I am puzzled on how to rotate them. can I include "rotate(90)" within the "transform"?

Comment: OK, I think I got this to work. I was way off. There had to be four groups with different id each. I needed to wrap each group in <defs> tag. Also, for each group, I needed to describe the form of transformation like the following: <g id="myGroup90" transform="rotate(90)">

Comment: If it is the exact same shape (only rotated) then you don't need to define it four times. Once will do.  You can put the transform on the `<use>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same definition. Just apply a different transform to each `<use>` element.

```html
<svg width="500" height="300"> 

  <defs>
    <g id="myGroup">
      <polygon points="50,5  100,5  125,30  125,80  100,105  50,105  25,80  25,30" style="stroke:#660000; fill:#cc3333; stroke-width:3;"/>
      <text x=38 y=65 font-family="san-serif" font-size="32px" fill="white">STOP</text>
    </g>
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#myGroup" />
  <use xlink:href="#myGroup" transform="translate(110,0) rotate(90, 75,55)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#myGroup" transform="translate(220,0) rotate(180, 75,55)"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: Oh, nice! Even though I completed the assignment, your code looks much simpler and makes more sense. Thanks!